# Could an Apex Predator grow into an intelligent society?

Tags: evolution

Humans don't exist, at least... not here. Instead we have [Insert non-lame animal name here:].

They're not too bright, but also could be considered vaguely self aware, about Gorilla level intelligence. They're roughly bipedal, but can get quite a trot going on all fours. They're thick skinned and durable, and can withstand blunt-force impact similar to being hit by a truck.

They're furry tanks, basically.

Obviously such a predator would be hard, if not impossible, to kill without an overwhelming numbers advantage and would most likely be the dominant species on the planet (as well as an absolute monster of an apex predator)... but with no threats to their position in the food chain, would they develop into what could be considered an advanced civilisation?

Would there be any reason to develop tools, invent things, if there was no survival requirement involved? Or would they stagnate and remain ape-like forever, like politicians?

**Edit**

Forgetting the Gorilla comparison, the question I'm asking is whether an intelligent, tool using, engine building, airplane flying civilisation could develop from a species that had few, if any, external threats? Assuming that humans developed the way you did in order to improve survival chances in a world where we weren't the toughest kid in school, would the toughest kid in school bother to develop in a similar way?

Comment: Given that gorillas are animals with roughly gorilla level intelligent, thick skinned, and durable, would the fact that gorillas did not form an intelligent society help form your answer?

Comment: Partially, what I'm thinking is... if we weren't here to influence (either positively or negatively) their development... would a bigger, stronger, tougher, version of a Gorilla community ever reach the Iron Age? Or Beyond? Time is not an issue, take as many years as you need.

Comment: Research is finding that species with significantly less complex brains than ours are capable of 'tool use', and manipulating their environment. But the way our evolution worked out, we had our last common ancestor with gorillas about 9 million years ago. If your question is 'could gorillas have developed intelligence and advanced tool use without becoming human', the answer is essentially yes. It wouldn't necessarily be a gorilla anymore, but the only reason humans aren't big furry killing machines(...well, bigger and furrier) is because it didn't work out that way.

Comment: I'm not sure if my question is clear, and I will try to edit it to make it better, but I'm not asking specifically about Gorillas, or Earth. Given a timeline of however-long-they-need, would there be any reason for an unchallenged predator to develop beyond the point where their survival is not threatened?

Comment: The mistake hear is that you think it matters that this critter is at the top of the food chain. It doesn't matter that they are already the best. Eventually something will survive better, or differently, and there will be a parting of evolutionary ways. If you want to write them to evolve so that they just happen to stay on top, that's actually highly likely, barring an extinction event. Just because selection pressure isn't coming from predation doesn't mean there is no selection pressure.

Comment: "... could develop from a species that had few, if any, external threats?"  This is exactly the opposite of what spurs on innovation and evolution.

Comment: Humans are an apex predator, so you may want to consider editing your title.

Comment: @Mikey, evolution isn't about what is innovative. It's about what works, and only in relation to what didn't work as well. There is no absolutism in evolution, because there isn't anything in evolution except evolution.

Comment: @SeanBoddy - if there is no threat to life or mate, and no scarcity, there's no need to self-select within your species the 'clever' ones who figured out how to get more.  But I see your social answer, and +1'ed it.

Comment: @Mikey, you make a strong point there that I hadn't considered, and one that the OP needs to consider in his timeline - in the absence of direct threats to survival itself, evolution is basically relying on mutation alone. It's probably going to take much, much longer to develop intelligence because it won't solve urgent needs. But, nonetheless, possible, unless they straight up decide to eat all the annoying nerds before they get fire and the wheel out of the deal.

Comment: [Potentially related question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/70925/what-kind-of-society-and-morals-would-an-alien-species-evolved-from-solitary-car/70928#70928)

Comment: Oh the arrogance  and ignorance in assuming that gorillas did form not an intelligent society.

Comment: Have humans formed an "intelligent" society yet? Asking for some friends.

Comment: Do you have cannibalism in this population of apex predators? That could provide a stimulus for evolution.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish I think you might be confusing Dominant Species (We are everywhere, like ants) with Apex Predator (We are squishy, and individually, fairly easy for a lot of animals to kill).

Comment: @Wompguinea We prey upon any animal we please, and no animal consistently preys upon us. That puts us at the top of the food chain. Hence Apex Predator.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish I'm sure the average bear, average lion or average wolf could quite easily win a fight with the average man. We're at the top through artificial advantages, not because we're naturally stronger.

Comment: @Wompguinea 1) Our "artificial" advantages are a product of our intelligence, which is "natural." 2) The food chain doesn't care if you're strong, smart, natural, artificial, genetically engineered, gluten-free, whatever. It cares about what eats and kills what. And we kill lions a lot more than lions kill us (600 lions killed by humans/year vs 250 people killed by lions/year).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**TL;DR - absolutely. Evolution doesn't stop just because you're good at something.**

Stop for a moment, and imagine a member of your species who is a perfect physical specimen, for whatever your selection criteria are for 'perfect'. Now imagine that you absolutely cannot bring yourself to engage in conversation with this person for more than five minutes at a time. Selection pressures have guided you into a position where this 'perfect' thing was overrated, and you will reevaluate your position on the definition of 'perfect'.

Similarly, the not-a-gorilla apex predator will make selections when mating, and given enough time, social dynamics come into play. Maybe it's like a lion's pride, and the strongest male gets all the dates. Maybe the female is the stronger of the species, and devours the male after conception. But one day, a not-a-gorilla is born who is different. Maybe he's just a LITTLE smarter. But he figures out that the females like gifts of flowers, or tasty critters to eat. He brings the tasty critters, doesn't get eaten and now he's very much more likely to survive to make more progeny than the ones that get eaten.

And it doesn't have to be social dynamics. The point is that there are SO MANY pressures causing evolution, that simply being on the top of the food chain isn't enough to stop that, especially over the long term. The point of my earlier comments on your post is that, after enough evolution happened to create advanced intelligence, the new not-a-gorilla is probably nothing like the old not-a-gorilla, in the same way that I'm only a very tiny little bit like an actual gorilla.

Minor Edit: I feel compelled to point out that when the not-a-gorilla has developed intelligence, I am in no way implying that it will be smaller, weaker, slower or mostly bald. We only turned out that way mostly by chance and choice. At some point, less fur became attractive. The advanced not-a-gorillas could have gotten bigger, faster, stronger, hairier, and more durable in the same time frame that they became intelligent. Evolution doesn't have an end game, it just comes down to who makes more and better babies.

Comment: May I submit for your consideration an example from history:
the shark.  Modern sharks evolved 100-60 million years ago.  In the time it's taken for us to to evolve from proto-rodents, the apex predator of the sea has changed very little.

Comment: @EasyTiger your point? -- you state that "the apex predator of the sea has changed **very little**", which means you yourself realize that they change (albeit more slowly than some other groups).

Comment: @errantlinguist I think the point is that given a bunch of hamsters and a bunch of sharks and a lot of time, there's a greater chance that one day a hamster will put a hamster on the moon, not because it is easy, but because it is hard.

Comment: @EasyTiger, I appreciate the point,  but orcas like tasty shark snacks. They breathe air, have complex brains, and social structures. Remember, the advanced not-a-gorilla and early not-a-gorilla are probably not going to be anything alike. An evolutionary branch does not necessarily lead to the end of the progenitor.

Comment: Even if these not-a-gorillas became intelligent and gained intelligence to rival that of Einstein, would they ever develop technology? They might be content with living as not-a-gorillas. Is there any precedence to claim they develop technology? (Let's assume they are mostly immune to the winter cold of their region and not bothered by summer heat).

Comment: @errantlinguist  It's a huge mistake to assume evolution drives towards intelligence.  Humans may be highly intelligent, but we're weak and slow, have a terrible sense of smell, and are very poorly adapted to any kind of life without clothes and tools.  We survived through being smart.  Sharks have changed, but strayed very little from their basic design because they're already pretty optimised for their conditions.

Comment: @EasyTiger the question is titled "**Could** an Apex Predator grow into an intelligent society?" not "**Will** an Apex Predator grow into an intelligent society?". Sharks, like all other creatures, continue to evolve. Ergo sharks **could** grow into an intelligent society.

Comment: @thegreatduck, the op wants to know if it's possible, and the answer is yes. And more to your point, once we developed intelligence,  we decided to continue developing technology. I don't need a robot butler, but gee golly wouldn't that be handy? After developing intelligence, they need to develop self awareness, scientific inquiry, and math to complete the vision in the post. I admit that these are steps this creature could miss. Gorillas have community, relationships, and inquisitive natures, but have no complex language (yet!), but the possibility absolutely exists.

Answer (score 11):

One theory of human brain development is based on [Social Intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_intelligence#Hypothesis). As humans began living in larger social groups (tribes and clans) our brains doubled in size to track these complex relationships. My sister's husband is off limits, but I can date my sister's husband's brother. My father's enemy's son is my enemy.... We have complex social rules which are fundamental to us, but really have no purpose in nature so it wouldn't evolve directly.

Instead, as the theory goes, we needed to keep track of who was who in the "in circle" around the various alpha positions and their families in society. If your family is close to the king this actually does impact your genetics, over and over in numerous ways. Children of the king's friends get married and you have an aristocracy – tracking a royal heir can sometimes be a societal obsession, and even in social animals [the children of alpha females are treated better](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotted_hyena#Social_behaviour) because of nepotism (nepotism literally means "nephew-ism").

Scheming men and women breed with the powerful, and they have powerful scheming children. This consolidates to an evolution of social intelligence that has nothing to do with mechanical engineering or scientific observation. It might however be related to language skills, persuasiveness, charisma. It also might explain cult leaders and narcissists who exploit a kind of social control over people even when it seems to defy logic.

How much of today's telecommunications and broadcast media is simply about the relationships of status individuals in society?

So if your critters have a strict social pecking order with lots of complicated rules they are expected to follow, they could be a society of backstabbing power-climbing schemers who are savvy and manipulative without necessarily being *hammer and screwdriver* intelligent.

Comment: An interesting idea, so... without the external threats of bigger, more powerful, animals to eat them they'd probably start to focus more on who in their own group is useful/dangerous and go from there.

Comment: And the control of resources, especially as those resources become more cooperative between larger communities (farms, armies).

Comment: "Nephew"-ism because popes didn't have children.

Comment: Interestingly, it would explain why the solitary white shark did not evolve so much while orcas which have a much more complex social structure are much more clever (to the point of being on display like dolphins). It's a nice theory for sure.

Comment: @Separatrix well, they promise not to at least. It's not like it would be hard for them to cover up. ;)

Answer (score 4):

I think it's entirely possible...

Once a creature is at the peak of the food chain its only competitors are its fellows. As in your creature could evolve to be intelligent simply by competing with others of its own species for mates and resources. Given a significant population this sort of competition becomes inevitable.

Answer (score 3):

The problem an Apex Predator has is having enough prey, and reducing energy expenditure to catch said prey so you come out ahead.

Once that is solved, the next problem is socialization.  There is reason to believe that humanity's intelligence developed to deal with other humans; we build complex social models to win the "in-tribe" dominance games and have more kids than the other humans.

So one issue is that your Apex Predator doesn't have much need to be social; in fact, a large group of such Apex Predators would starve as they consumed all the prey in an area.

Trying to scale up the prey as well runs into problems, as your size gets larger your N gets smaller, and smaller N leads to more instability.

However, what if we presume our Apex Predator forms a symbiotic relationship with a prey species; the Apex Predator becomes a herding species.  They herd one kind of herbivore, which they use only when short other food, while they hunt other food.

Clashes between herders require their impressive size and strength, as does hunting other species.  Herding requires more than one of them, providing socialization and a red queen's race of intelligence within the social groups.

The herd animals being larger than them would also provide a reason for them to be strong.  They would cull the most aggressive, but they would still have to deal with brontosaurus sized cows.

Similar symbiosis occurs in nature without intelligence.  So it isn't completely ridiculous that it would precede the development of intelligence, then lead to more developing.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it isn't likely.

Intelligence is a big investment.  The young develop slower since you have to teach them.  You have to grow a bigger brain that consumes a lot of energy. Luckily meat is energy dense compared to plant matter but there is still the question: why did the species bother?

Intelligence develops to solve problems.  So, you have to figure out what problem arose that intelligence was needed to solve?

One possibility is that intelligence led the creature to become the apex predator.  By using their intelligence they removed their rivals (like with us).  However, if the predator had more going for it (speed, claws, poison, armor, etc.) then once it was smart enough to remove the threat, it wouldn't need to get any smarter.

Comment: This isn't exactly right. Intelligence didn't develop because problems needed to be solved. It developed in little steps, by chance  and selection pressure, and the problems it solved made the members of the species who had it more likely to survive than the ones who didn't.

Comment: @SeanBoddy, yes but I think that it was the pressure of the problems that made the incremental changes in intelligence into survival benefits.  The brain power that we spend reasoning is taken, partially from out ability to process scents and map the world by them.  Intelligence had to be worth enough to give that up.

Comment: Human hearing is an ongoing real time fourier analysis that can reliably tell the difference between a softball hitting a concrete floor, or a baseball hitting drywall, in real time. Intelligence is worth a lot, and durable meat eaters have abundant energy. Our olfactory senses don't match those of dogs, but that's because in relation, our systems give us the advantage, in terms of evolution. You aren't wrong either, but my point is that your last comment is more correct than supposing intelligence developed for a reason. It simply developed, and just happened to be a survival trait.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, evolution was spurred by natural bottlenecks like droughts, ice ages, isolation etc,. more than competition with other predators. Make one ice age 1 degree colder or hotter and it would have turned out vastly different. Humans would be physically, mentally, and socially widely divergent from what we are now if we survived at all.

Other species were at comparable levels many times in our prehistory. So complex civilisation for your unnamed predator could have been a result of needing to cooperate and develop social systems as a means of survival against a series of natural events rather than competition against other animals.

Answer (score 2):

The trouble apex predators have re: continued evolution isn't that they have no predators etc, it's that they can go anywhere they want to.

When a mutation occurs it's chances of recurring sufficient to become an emergent property of a species are massively diminished in a large genepool. This, not any other factor, is the primary reason why Apex anything don't tend to evolve much.

Humans have bred plants and animals by doing what nature does..inbreeding. Yes, that's right.. you wouldn't be as smart as you are if it wasn't for inbreeding.

Isolation begets evolution. With this in mind, Apex (walking, hopping or slithering) predators can reasonably be expected to evolve 'further' if some event isolates a breeding population from the greater whole.

In fish, & birds this is clearly harder to achieve, given that natural events that can dislocate one breeding population from another are...well, they don't really happen very often at all. Some species have essentially locked themselves into their path by various forms of ingrained migration tactics, which whilst helping the species survive in many senses, essentially drop it from the list of "species that might go somewhere"

Answer (score 1):

Why not look to the oceans of Earth?

**Orca/ Killer Whales** are Apex Predators and have been for quite some period of time. They have social behaviour and work together to form complex hunting techniques to take down most other creatures around.

However, they do not appear to have developed the ability to create supermarines (reverse submarines) to conquer land, nor the need to use tools, create industry, engineer items, etc - all things that we deem necessary as an advanced civilization - even if the development of nets would aid them capturing prey, housing could provide shelter for their young, glass-walled air-tanks to keep naked chimps in as pets...

Comment: Hello and welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! Interesting start. But I think something is missing. The OP asks if things like engine building, tool using, etc. would be likely. Your last paragraph looks like you state that it would not be possible, but could potentially benefit this species. Is there a way you see to make this work? For example what would be needed to make Orcas use tools, etc. A final short statement about your opinion would be nice. If you got quesionts take the tour and visit the help center. Have fun!

Comment: A supermarine goes over water, a superterra goes over land.

Comment: @Separatrix, this is my quote of the day. :D

Comment: Orcas do use tools, but perhaps are simply limited in their level of tool creation by the lack of opposable thumbs / lack of dexterity in general.

Answer (score 1):

There would be no reason for them to evolve if they don't compete amongst themselves or have some external forces working against them, because they're dominant. Look at some animals that have stayed pretty much the same for millions of years because they reached a kind've happy medium.

Answer (score 0):

**One critical factor is missing - tool using.**

As has been pointed out social predators like orca and to a lesser extent lions and wolves by default have more or less complex means of communication. None of them however develop tool using abilities of any significant because they are not equipped by evolution to do so.

Your gorilla like predators have mass and speed and use them to hunt effectively. They don't *need* tools to extract resources from their environment. Our ancestors weren't equipped by nature with fangs, claws or speed. But by the time of the arrival of Homo Sapiens our ancestors had *become* apex predators - they just didn't start out as one. They had to learn how to become the most feared killers on the planet.

Your creatures don't have that problem, they are already top of the heap.  They may be intelligent, self aware and communicative but they will never build a city. What environmental pressure is there to force them to become tool using? The only possibility is larger/more dangerous foes and perhaps a changing environment where the 'old' way of obtaining calories was no longer as effective as it used to be?  (I.E. the same things that forced our early ancestors out of the forests and onto the savannas.

Comment: There's one factor that's being overlooked: all "apex predator" means is that it's the top of the food chain. That does *not* by definition mean that an individual specimen is the biggest, meanest, toughest critter in the neighbourhood. Wolves are apex predators. An individual wolf can be killed by an elk or a bison. A bison could take on a number of wolves and win.

Comment: True, all apex predators face completion, not just from others of their own species but also lessor predators who diminish potential prey numbers in the local area. (That's part of the reason lions will hunt down and kill leopards and cheetahs if they can.) Also as you noted, at least on Earth the fight or flight response means if they can't escape prey animals will turn and fight. The problem these guys have is that they have already evolved effective hunting strategies that don't rely on tool using. Something in their environment has to change radically to drive their species down that path.

Answer (score 0):

The evolutionary pressures on your apex predator are internal to their species.  There are two ways that one predator can out-compete another using intelligence.

1. Social.  A predator can make better alliances, bring down foes, scheme better.
2. Tools.  A smaller, weaker predator can use tools to compensate for being weak.  It may even use tools to get food that the larger, stronger predators can't get.  Such as learning to paddle a piece of driftwood to get out to the island where the other ones can't hunt.